# How to abstract the events of different modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use two different modules. (Let's say module1 and module2.) Both modules fire a `data` event when they receive data.

```
var mod1 = require('./module1');
var mod2 = require('./module2');

mod1.on(`data`, listener());
mod2.on(`data`, listener());
```

I want to be able to invoke the common listener without being aware of different modules.
For example, can you use something like an interface or an abstract class to do the following?

```
for (let step = 0; step < 10; step++) {
  var mod = new ModFactory();
  mod.on(`data`, commonListener())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

1. Create a third module you can call something like `event-source`.  Have it export a single `eventEmitter` object (a singleton).
2. Have both mod1 and mod2 use that `event-source` module and send events to that eventEmitter that the `event-source` created.
3. Then have your other code that wants to receive these messages also load the `event-source` module and put listeners on its singleton eventEmitter.

In this way, the listening code does not need to know anything about where the events came from and it can listen to them all on one eventEmitter object.

The listening code would just do this:

```
// get common event source
const eventSource = require('./event-source');
// listen for incoming data events
eventSource.on('data', myListener);
```

And, inside of `mod1` and `mod2`, then would do this:

```
// get common event source
const eventSource = require('./event-source');
```

And, then somewhere inside their code, they would emit to that:

```
eventSource.emit('data', someData);
```

In this way, `mod1` and `mod2` are always going to send messages to the same eventEmitter which any outside code can retrieve and then listen to.

---

A little bit more flexible way of doing things would be to restructure `mod1` and `mod2` so that you pass into them what `eventEmitter` you want them to emit to (in some sort of module constructor function).  Then your outside module could create its own eventEmitter and pass that to both `mod1` and `mod2` when they are loaded.  This keeps `mod1` and `mod2` two as still independent modules and lets the caller decide what `eventEmitter` object they emit to.  It could set them up to both use the same eventEmitter or it could send them separate eventEmitter objects - however it wanted to configure things.

---

And, as Bergi suggested, you could create the common eventEmitter yourself, listen to both the eventEmitters from `mod1` and `mod2` and forward their messages to the common eventEmitter.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const mod1 = require('./module1');
const mod2 = require('./module2');

const commonEmitter = new EventEmitter();
function forwardEvent(data) {
    commonEmitter.emit('data', data);
}
mod1.on(`data`, forwardEvent);
mod2.on(`data`, forwardEvent);
```

Then, anyone who wants data events from either `mod1` or `mod2` can get them from the `commonEmitter`.

Comment: …and a third way would be to just import the existing `mod1` and `mod2` event emitters into the third `eventEmitter`, and forward their events manually.

Comment: @Bergi - I added that option also.